# Why does the jQuery website use version 1.4.2 of its library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked through the jQuery forums and not found anything about this. So I was wondering, if the jQuery framework is improving all the time (and up to version 1.7.1 at time of writing), then why doesn't the jQuery website itself use the latest verison?

I expect the answer may be something like "because it doesn't need the latest features" or "if it ain't broke don't fix it", but I would have thought they would be championing their own latest work.

Could anybody shed some light on this? I feel the real answer might be useful to other people with jQuery driven websites that have considered or are considering upgrading.

Comment: What jQuery plugins does the site use, if any? It might be for compatibility reasons.

Comment: The API page (http://api.jquery.com/) uses 1.7.1.

Comment: Short of someone from the jQuery team, or their web-devs, answering (and declaring their involvement) this question isn't objectively answerable and is, therefore, [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). While I'm *interested* in the speculation, and potential reasons, I'm voting to close as 'not constructive.' ...sorry.

Comment: I also used an earlier version of Jquery (1.4), My reason? Well I tried the latest version and it didnt work with the jQuery Address plugin (latest version).

Comment: Since this is already closed, you could try asking the question on the [jQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/).

Comment: It could be a combination of reasons:

1) Plugin size (probably 1.4 is smaller, so the page loading time is shorter, and the website gets ranked higher in Google)

2) No need for latest features in the website (they are not using them)

3) Laziness (no need to change the plugin to its latest version if it is working great)

4) Users cache. Probably they have found that 1.4 version is the most widely used, so probably there is higher chance to found it cached in client's browser more often than the latest version.

Many other reasons... just contact them and ask for the real reason :)

Comment: I'm rather disappointed this was closed. Sure, it's a question that requires a certain type of person to answer, but don't they all? Certainly some of the qns I read from those who voted to close this qn have had posted fairly open ended qns in the past. *And* I'm fairly convinced the real answer would have been good to know for lots of jQuery developers. Oh well.

Comment: Within reason, yes: *every* question requires a certain type of person to answer. Unfortunately this question requires a member of a *specific* ***team*** to offer a valid answer, which is why I voted to close as 'not constructive,' as we have no reason to believe that the only people who *could* answer participate on this site, or would see this question. I am, however, sorry for having to vote to close, as I would have been interested in the potential answers.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the reply. I'll try the jQuery forums. I admit that would be a more proper forum for the question, but I thought that the audience here would be wider and possibly more appreciative of this particular answer. I myself come to StackOverflow first for jQuery Q/A because I like the format and the community tends to have the same qns I do.